# CABasicAnimation chaining not working

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

I am having difficulties chaining multiple `CABasicAnimation`s. I just want to make a button scale to 1.5 times it's size, then to 0.5 and fade away (while scaling down).

The problem is that only the scaling up works then the button goes back to the original state.

I would have used `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` but it creates a bug in iOS 7. On iOS 8 & 9 it works fine

I tried using a `CAAnimationGroup` but same result.

Here's the code:

```
    let scaleUp = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    scaleUp.fromValue = 1
    scaleUp.toValue = 1.5
    scaleUp.duration = 0.2
    scaleUp.beginTime = 0
    scaleUp.removedOnCompletion = true
    self.myButton.layer.addAnimation(scaleUp, forKey: "up")

    let scaleDown = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    scaleDown.fromValue = 1
    scaleDown.toValue = 0.5
    scaleDown.duration = 0.2
    scaleDown.beginTime = scaleUp.beginTime + scaleDown.duration
    scaleDown.removedOnCompletion = true
    self.myButton.layer.addAnimation(scaleDown, forKey: "down")

    let fade = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    fade.fromValue = 1
    fade.toValue = 0
    fade.duration = 0.2
    fade.beginTime = scaleUp.beginTime + scaleDown.duration
    fade.removedOnCompletion = false
    self.myButton.layer.addAnimation(fade, forKey: "fade")
```

Comment: Do you want a bouncy effect complemented with fading?

Comment: Yes. Button Press -> Scale Up -> Scale Down & Fade

Comment: so... where is your actual chain? I see three independent animations here only.

Comment: I just wrote what a few up voted answers said. If you know how to do it properly then please show me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that works for me quite well, feel free to play with the duration times, or other animation properties.

I tried to use your instructions for the animation, but it does not mean I have set all properties correctly for your expectations.

---

#### Swift (2.x)

```
func addGrowShrinkAndFadeOutAnimationToView(viewToAnimate: UIView) {

    let easeInOutTiming = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

    let viewScaleXAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.x")
    viewScaleXAnimation.duration = 0.4
    viewScaleXAnimation.values = [1.0 as Float, 1.5 as Float, 0.5 as Float]
    viewScaleXAnimation.keyTimes = [0.0 as Float, 0.5 as Float, 1.0 as Float]
    viewScaleXAnimation.timingFunctions = [easeInOutTiming, easeInOutTiming]
    viewToAnimate.layer.addAnimation(viewScaleXAnimation, forKey:"Grow, Shrink and Fade out_ScaleX")

    let viewScaleYAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.y")
    viewScaleYAnimation.duration = 0.4
    viewScaleYAnimation.values = [1.0 as Float, 1.5 as Float, 0.5 as Float]
    viewScaleYAnimation.keyTimes = [0.0 as Float, 0.5 as Float, 1.0 as Float]
    viewScaleYAnimation.timingFunctions = [easeInOutTiming, easeInOutTiming]
    viewToAnimate.layer.addAnimation(viewScaleYAnimation, forKey:"Grow, Shrink and Fade out_ScaleY")

    let viewOpacityAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    viewOpacityAnimation.duration = 0.4
    viewOpacityAnimation.values = [1.0 as Float, 1.0 as Float, 0.0 as Float]
    viewOpacityAnimation.keyTimes = [0.0 as Float, 0.5 as Float, 1.0 as Float]
    viewOpacityAnimation.timingFunctions = [easeInOutTiming, easeInOutTiming]
    viewToAnimate.layer.addAnimation(viewOpacityAnimation, forKey:"Grow, Shrink and Fade out_Opacity")

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabor! I did the necessary changes and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you want to use CA animations? I find manipulating constraints easier. I have added a button in storyboard and created outlets for the height and width constraints of the button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var buttonWidth : CGFloat?
var buttonHeight : CGFloat?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.buttonHeight = self.heightConstraint.constant
    self.buttonWidth = self.widthConstraint.constant
}

@IBAction func okButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    let animationDuration = 2.0
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.buttonWidth! * 2.0
    self.widthConstraint.constant = self.buttonHeight! * 2.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
       button.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) in
            self.heightConstraint.constant = self.buttonWidth! * 0.5
            self.widthConstraint.constant = self.buttonHeight! * 0.5
            UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
                button.alpha = 0.0
                button.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { (finished) in
                   button.hidden = true
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really like to mess with constraints. I use CAAnimation because I want the app to be compatible with iOS 7 but CGAffineTransformMakeScale doesn't work properly on iOS 7 and it creates a bug.